# Old EntityFramework DLL referenced somewhere in project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently receiving the following error when I build my MVC 5 project.

"Failed to resolve assembly reference. The path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll' must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone. If you have downloaded this template, you may need to 'Unblock' it using the properties page for the template file in File Explorer"

The problem started after I had an issue with my hard drive and had to re-install VS 2013. It is no longer installed on the D drive. I salvaged the project and simply reused it with the new installation of VS (on Windows 7).

I have also removed Entity Framework 6.1.1 from the project and re-installed to no avail. I seem to have a reference somewhere in the project and so far unable to find it.

I am relatively new to Visual Studio and any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: try looking in the project file - open it in a text editor and see if there is a reference to it in there.  You can then try removing it although I'd take a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just ran a text search of the entire folder and cannot locate any text in the project with "D:\Program Files"

Comment: `EntityFramework.dll` does not belong in there at all AFAIK. Try deleting it. Else search the registry.

Comment: Started with the registry. Search found some references, but nothing that looked like it would cause the issue... Deleted them anyway, restarted VS, error is gone. Thanks! Now to figure out how to mark as answered.

Comment: @leppie, post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: @thefid: I have enough rep, you do it ;p

Comment: Leppie, thanks again for your answer... I don't think I get anything if I answer it... First person to copy and paste Leppie's answer above gets the reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is posted in the comments of the original question. The reference was in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is easy to resolve, your project's references going to the old paths, check the references in the solution explorer.

it'S sure the exist some references with an alert signal. you need change the path of this ref to the correct place, maybe exist more references with problems.

or install entity for nuget package

/tools / nuget / nuget console

and write

Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.1

Comment: Leppie provided the answer in a comment above... Thanks for your response, however I mentioned in the question that I uninstalled and re-installed EntityFramework.